# Setup DoD CAC (smartcard)

Tags: smartcard

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.6, using the terminal pcsc_scan shows my smartcard information so my hardware and initial software are working. When I use a browser,either Edge or Firefox, they do not recognize my CAC (smartcard). What additional steps do I need to get my certificate in the browser and install the DoD certificates?